# Can we do a command line export of Oracle 11g forms reports domain from a WL (10.3.6) server to other server(10.3.6) running on a different machine

Tags: oracle, forms, weblogic11g, wlst

If yes can someone please share a link, my understanding is that we do we have to have software only install of 11g forms and reports on the target server and we will use this exported domain to build another environment there. My client does not want to have a server with GUI so I need some pointers to how to use WLST in this case if possible.